# Is there a way to programmatically detect the SET IDENTITY_INSERT xyz ON/OFF settings?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

[SESSIONPROPERTY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175001%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) returns some of the `SET` options settings of a session (but not IDENTITY_INSERT).

Is there a programmatically get the `SET IDENTITY_INSERT xyz ON` settings?

Comment: This thread suggests it might only be possible by trying and parsing the error http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic491092-8-1.aspx as does this one http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/1a6ba2bb-5e82-47e8-a1a0-16fc044b951e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't pretty, but if you can't find another way:

```
BEGIN TRY
    CREATE TABLE #temp (my_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL)
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #temp ON
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT #temp OFF
    DROP TABLE #temp
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    SELECT ERROR_MESSAGE()
    DROP TABLE #temp
END CATCH
```

You could then parse the result from ERROR_MESSAGE() to find out the table name (if any) for which it is set. If I find a better way then I'll replace this answer.